# Testing parser for oauth2 implicit grant access_token in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oauth-2.0

I'm writing angular application that uses implicit grant oauth strategy. If I don't have valid access token in my cookies I am redirected to web interface of authentication server, input my credentials and get redirected to my site with access token in the url. My system parses it and writes down into cookies.

Currently I faced question of unit testing this parse function that consumes the url and returns access token object. Can't think the good way, so writing here:

**1. How do you approach unit testing (so I can't make direct request to working oauth server) a function that parses the access token from authentication server?**

**2. How do you build url params with access token? Will it be secure if I copy current access token and use it in test data?**

**3. Are there libraries that can aid creation of mock access token object?**

Answer (score 2):

You could breakout "just enough" OAuth, like the service linked below. This will give you a super-basic OAuth provider, but is really geared to "integration testing" scenarios (depending on where you draw the lines on these things).

If you want to be a unit-testing purist/zealot, then you could fork this into your app's unit test code.

https://github.com/zalando-stups/mocks/tree/master/oauth2-provider

In lieu of a great answer, here's one to get you out of a hole :)

Comment: This is very interesting! But I hoped that there is a library that generates the access token object, not mocks the whole oAuth service. That should be possible, right?

Answer (score 1):

After approaching authors of my oAuth authentification service I've got insight on the data the server was sending me in case of successful authentication. In my case the response from oAuth server has the following form:

1. **header**       // encoded algorithm for has creation
2. **access token** // base64 encoded object
3. **hash**         // of the 3 previous items done using algorithm specified in the header.

It has the following structure: **header.access_token.hash**

My fear for security breach was concerned about putting correct data (that I can get from browser) into the test files. But as it turns out the token will not be valid without correct hash. The hashing of the token data is done in server side using private key, so if I change the hash the token will become obsolete.

As my token-parsing-function that I wanted to check uses only the **access_token part** of the request, I've changed the header and hash parts and also encoded other user name for sake of testing purposes.

So this is the resolution of my current problem. Hope this will help somebody.